# Fatal error: Class 'database' not found - PHP

Tags: php

When I attempt to use the problem class I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'database' not found in path/problem.php on line 25
```

I don't understand why I got this error, at the top of problem.php I require database.php. What is happening?

problem.php

```
<?php
require("common.php");
require("database.php");
...
?>
```

database.php

```
<?php
class database
{
    ...
}
?>
```

Comment: Can you provide the exact code?

Comment: Are problem.php and database.php in the same folder?

Comment: Ciprian L.: That is the exact code. What do you mean?
Eric: Yep.

Comment: At which point is `problem` instantiated?

Comment: Are all the files in the same directory?

Comment: Ohhh. I have it now. It was instantiated in the parent directoy. I didn't seem to figure that out. Thanks guys!

Comment: It might a problem with your include_path or having multiple scripts with that name lying around. Try `include("./database.php")` with a ./ explicit or even absolute path.

Comment: gore, that would not matter as database should be in scope as its required in the same file as the class, although for classes he really should be using `require_once`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

this is probably an include path issue. In order to fix it, in your problem.php file

do this:

```
echo realpath (dirname(__FILE__));
```

that will output something like

/var/www/html/myfilepath/

your file, problem.php will be in that dir.

now, if database.php is also in that dir, you can do this

```
$filepath = realpath (dirname(__FILE__));

require_once($filepath."/database.php");
```

if it is somewhere else you can do

```
require_once($filepath."/../../path/to/somewhere/else/database.php");
```

Comment: /var/www/html/spring-php/controllers/../../model/User.php This is what i getting. Please help

Answer (score 1):

do you include the file?

```
 include "database.php"; // or the path relative to database.php
 class problem
{
```

nevermind.
Maybe :the include (required) is not opening the file.

Comment: It is the 3rd line of problem.php

Answer (score 0):

Can you add

```
echo "OK";
```

to footer of the database.php and check again?

So, we can understand, database.php is really included to page .

Comment: It is not showing up... Why would that be? database.php is in the same directory.

Comment: OK. Now can you check directly database.php ? When you look at to database.php , it's showing OK ? Or just blank page ? If blank page returned, you make syntax mistake on database.php.

Answer (score -1):

for posterity: just to clarify the reason this fails is that you are including from the point of view of the ORIGINAL call let me explain giving the example:

```
myfolder/index.php
<?php
 include ("classes/problem.php");
 ...
?>
```

this means that by the time you get to "`problem.php`" and mention "`database.php`" you're in "`myfolder/`" as far as PHPland is concerned not "`myfolder/classes`" (which you'd need to be in for this to make sense). The right way to do it is to simply use absolute paths for everything via a constant made on line 1 page 1. I know it's what a lot of people say is horrible - but in all honesty it's what "namespaces" are supposed to fix but I would still use constants (IMHO namespaces are awful in php, and are more to do with self-aggrandisement/ open source advertising/ authorship ego boasting agenda that anything concrete or useful)